# converting string to float in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to convert a data from string to float and insert it to MYSQL database. $data variable is a string. Here's my SQL query:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
               id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               stockcode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
               lastprice FLOAT NOT NULL,
               open FLOAT NOT NULL,
               close FLOAT NOT NULL,
               low FLOAT NOT NULL,
               high FLOAT NOT NULL
           )";


$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

$i = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($i++ < 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $a = array();
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        if ($i++ < 1) {
            continue;
        }
        array_push($a, floatval($cell->nodeValue));
    }
    print_r($a);
    var_dump($a);
    echo "<hr/>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (stockcode, lastprice, open, close, low, high)
        VALUES ( '" . $data[0] . "', '" . $data[1] . "', '" . $data[4] . "',   '" . $data[7] . "', '" . $data[5] . "', '" . $data[6] . "')";
```

But it still gives me error : PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/mysqlcon.php on line 79

Comment: show us the data array

Comment: I guess you have to use something like `floatval( $data[n]->nodeValue )`, but if you edit question adding a `var_dump` of `$data` we can better help you.

Comment: Consider using PDO and bound tokens, rather than just inlining variables into your mysql statements. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: i tried using that but to no avail. var_dump outputs to float but when i tried inserting it to MYSQL it creates the error @fusion3k

Comment: Post more relevant code (your `$data` construction)

Comment: That's because you try to convert object to string, pay attention to line 79 and debug from there. From your code i can't see where is line 79.

Comment: i posted my 3/4 codes kindly recheck guys

Comment: line 79 is in: VALUES ( '" . $data[0] . "', '" . $data[1] . "', '" . $data[4] . "',   '" . $data[7] . "', '" . $data[5] . "', '" . $data[6] . "')"; i don't the proper sql query to insert values in table. How can I leave them as float values. @RyanVincent

Comment: here's the result of my my var_dump in my array. { [0]=> float(2) [1]=> float(7.41) [2]=> float(0.1) [3]=> float(1.37) [4]=> float(7.36) [5]=> float(7.36) [6]=> float(7.5) [7]=> float(7.31) [8]=> float(333) [9]=> float(2) } @RyanVincent

Comment: That error message is not for that array. Why?, that array contains all float values.  The error message is complaining about a trying to convert an object to a string - and failing. So, You are not showing information that relates to that error message?

Comment: Yup the error is in SQL query. I just copied the error from error.log of apache @RyanVincent

Comment: IF I comment out the   $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(stockcode, lastprice, open, close, low, high) VALUES ($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[7], $data[5], $data[6])"; the error disappears.@RyanVincent

Comment: I forgot I had change $data to $a but still the error occurs. @RyanVincent

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the float number between two quotations

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table(stockcode, lastprice, open, close, low, high)
   VALUES ( '".$data[0]."', '".floatval($data[1])."', '".floatval($data[4])."', '".floatval($data[7])."', '".floatval($data[5])."', '".floatval($data[6])."')";
```

even it's a number should be between two quotations

Comment: Why? BTW This is not the problem. The error is not about MySQL query, it is about casting values.